# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable when insert tweet data to mysql Python 3

Tags: python, mysql, tweepy, pymysql

This is my code to insert tweet data in MYSQL

```
import pymysql
import tweepy
import time
import json
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import pymysql.cursors

ckey= ''
csecret= ''
atoken=''
asecret=''

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='admin1234', db='mysql')
cur = conn.cursor()

class listener(StreamListener):

 def on_data(self, data):
        all_data = json.loads(data)
        tweet = all_data["text"]
        a=0
        #username = all_data["user"]["screen_name"]

        cur.execute("INSERT INTO tweet (textt) VALUES (%s)" (tweet))
        print (tweet)
        return True

def on_error(self, status):
    print (status)

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track = ["puasa"])

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

but i get error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

traceback error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "collect-sql.py", line 40, in <module>
    twitterStream.filter(track = ["puasa"])
  File "/Users/amzar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 450, in filter
    self._start(async)
  File "/Users/amzar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 364, in _start
    self._run()
  File "/Users/amzar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 297, in _run
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/amzar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/amzar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 266, in _run
    self._read_loop(resp)
  File "/Users/amzar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 327, in _read_loop
    self._data(next_status_obj)
  File "/Users/amzar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 300, in _data
    if self.listener.on_data(data) is False:
  File "collect-sql.py", line 30, in on_data
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO tweet (textt) VALUES (%s)" (tweet))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: You're missing a comma in `cur.execute("INSERT INTO tweet (textt) VALUES (%s)" (tweet))` after the string and before `(tweet))`

Comment: cur.execute("INSERT INTO tweet (textt) VALUES (%s)", (tweet))

like this?

Comment: @roganjosh i got this error after update the code

UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u201c' in position 97: ordinal not in range(256)

Comment: Yes. `()` is the syntax for calling a function so without the comma, Python thinks you're calling a function, but it's actually a string.

Comment: @roganjosh that is not true about the `()` I can write `(mystring)` all day and no attempt at a function call ever happens. By not having a comma after the variable name however, it is not being interpreted as a tuple.

Comment: @rbricheno ofc it's true. You could test this with `print('hello'('something'))` and the error is question clearly `'str' object is not callable`, exactly as the OP has in their question title. The parser is interpreting it as a function call. In `(mystring)` the brackets are doing nothing; in fact, brackets are not required to define a tuple at all. `a = 2,` will define a tuple, simply because of the comma. They're only required here because it wouldn't be possible to determine whether you were passing more than 2 arguments to `execute()` (which, note, uses `()` to denote a function call).

Comment: @roganjosh sorry, my confusion, I thought you were trying to say "surrounding a string with brackets causes it to be called as a function". Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 2 extra commas:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO tweet (textt) VALUES (%s)", (tweet,))
```

The first separates the query string from the arguments, the second turns the value in brackets into the first element in a 1 element tuple (it actually [would work](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/9105a9ebc98e280a3a4731bec928277714ae6a93/pymysql/cursors.py#L129) if you just used a single string instead of a tuple, assuming you only have one argument, but this isn't officially supported from the look of things).

But this error that you mentioned in the comments:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u201c' in position 97: ordinal not in range(256)
```

means you are trying to interpret unicode text containing a character from the extended character set into `latin-1`.

If the field is already internally defined (in your mysql database) as unicode, you may need to specify the character set to use when connecting e.g.:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='admin1234', db='mysql', use_unicode=True, charset="utf8")
```

If the field in mysql is not already something like utf-8 then I recommend you alter or otherwise redefine the database to use a unicode character se tfor this column.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-mysql.html

Comment: Thank you @rbricheno for your helping :)

Comment: The reason you need to convert `(tweet,)` into a tuple is because a string is an iterable sequence. If you're passing a single string to your query without encapsulating it in another iterable, python will instead iterate the characters of the string and try unpack them one-by-one into the query, which will almost always throw an error because there aren't enough binding parameters to hold each character; and it's very unlikely to be what you intended anyway :)